# date half month not working

Tags: php, date

I tried to do like this

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('0.5 months'));
```

But it gives me date **1970-01-01**

Expected date is **2017-10-15**

So the question is why the half month is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use non-integers in a `strtotime()` [relative date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php):

> number    [+-]?[0-9]+

To make this work, you can use either `2 weeks` or `15 days` (note that these two return different days, since 2 weeks is 14 days):

```
<?php
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2 weeks")).PHP_EOL; // 2017-10-15
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("15 days")).PHP_EOL; // 2017-10-16
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+.5 months")).PHP_EOL; // not valid, returns 1970-01-01
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/EQli1)

Comment: For anyone wondering; if you need decimals above 1.0 so for example 3.5 months in the future, you can use multiple expressions in strtotime: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('3 months 15 days'));`
Or if you wanted -2.5 months in the past: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('- 2 months - 15 days'));` etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot the Plus singn

Please try with below

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ 0.5 months'));
```

or 
`date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ 15 days'));` 
(If you convert in days)
hope will help you

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for a solution using only php relative time for a half month. The problem with the previous answers is that they don’t take into account the fluctuation in the amount of days per month. Consider this:

```
$time = strtotime('last day of feb 2019');
$time = strtotime('-2 weeks', $time);
$formatted_date = date('m/d', $time);
```

Output is `02/14` which is exactly in the middle of the month. But what about this:

```
$time = strtotime('last day of jan');
$time = strtotime('-2 weeks', $time);
$formatted_date = date('m/d', $time);
```

Output is `01/17`, which is 1-2 days off from the *true* middle of the month (01/15.5) depending on if you round up or down.

Also, per the answer with `strtotime('+0.5 months')`, I know this was addressed, but this is an excerpt straight from the PHP docs:

> *number* is an *integer* number; if a decimal number is given, the dot (or comma) is likely interpreted as delimiter. For instance, '+1.5 hours' is parsed like '+1 5 hours', not as '+1 hour +30 minutes'.

I’ve experimented with quite a few phrasings to get to the true middle of the month, and I’ve come to the conclusion that it isn’t possible with relative formats alone. So here is my solution:

```
<?php
function middleOfMonth( $time ) {
    $n = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, date('n', $time), date('Y', $time) );
    return $n / 2;
}

$time = strtotime('jan next year');
$middle = middleOfMonth( $time ); // result is 15.5
echo( ceil( $middle ) ); // outputs 16
echo( floor( $middle ) ); // outputs 15
```